# Async pipe still executing despite *ngIf evaluating to false

Tags: asynchronous, angular, angular2-pipe

I'm having problems with the async pipe as I would like a list to being able to depend on both async and static data. I can't understand how to do this in a clever way however.

Right now it looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngIf="true" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item}}</li>
  <li *ngIf="false" *ngFor="let item of list | async">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here's the extremely annoying part though, even if `*ngIf` is false, the async pipe will still try to do its thing. Causing the app to crash and throw an error saying that the async pipe has the wrong type of argument since it expects a promise rather than an array.

So my question is, why does it do this and what would be a better and more correct way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Set the value of a boolean variable true or false in your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the model so that even when your data is static, the template gets an observable. This can be easily done with `Observable.of()`

For instance, suppose that you typically get the observable from a `getData()` function, but that when the data is static, you get it from `getStaticData()` function. You would do:

**model**

```
if(isDataStatic){
    //convert static data into an observable that emits that data
    this.list = Observable.of(this.getStaticData());
}else{
    //however you typically get the observable
    this.list = this.getData();
}
```

As a result, `list` will always be an observable, even when your data is static. The template can remain simple.

**template**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list | async">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hmm.. Any idea how I can convert the list to an observable if it already isn't one, inside the component before the template loads?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz `Observable.of(this.list)` will return an Observable that emits the list.

Comment: Yes I know, but how can I check if it's an Observable or not?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz `this.list instanceof Observable` will return `true` if it's an Observable. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.10/doc/spec.md#4.19.4